# ssl nginx ошибка

Tags: nginx, openssl

сгенерировал сертификаты

➜  nginx

sudo openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout  /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt

в настройках пути гарантированно верные в файле конфига (в ошибке верный путь говорит)

проверяю

➜  nginx

sudo nginx -t

```
2019/08/07 13:16:15 [warn] 4355#4355: the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ppluschat.loc.conf:11
2019/08/07 13:16:15 [warn] 4355#4355: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
Enter PEM pass phrase:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

➜  nginx

journal -xe ->

```
2019/08/07 13:17:18 [emerg] 4387#4387: cannot load certificate key "/etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:while reading strings error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password error:0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey:bad password read)
```

Содержимое: 
➜  nginx ls -alh ssl

```
итого 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K авг  7 13:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4,0K авг  7 12:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,3K авг  7 13:15 cert.crt
-rw------- 1 root root 1,9K авг  7 13:15 cert.key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно удалить ключеву фразу:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out newkey.pem
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#key-removepass):

Comment: key.pem имеется ввиду в моем случае как cert.key?

Comment: @АртурБелов,  Да